# Uber API: https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price …? takes ~ 1.5-2 sec which is too large .Is there a way to reduce the time?

Tags: api, uber-api

If any one knows Uber API best practises, then please let me know. Google Driving and Transit API takes less than 100 milliseconds and Uber API takes more than 1 sec.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any specific recommendations to reduce the time. That amount is higher than we are seeing for most hits to /v1.2/estimates/price over the last 7 days but is at the upper range for all requests to that endpoint.

The Uber API team will continue working on optimizing and improving speed for the Uber API. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the response
Is there any specific constraint such that like if the source and destination are very far, say 50 miles apart, then the API will take more time?

Comment: Nothing specific to comment here. No recommendations to reduce the time.